# Why is vector.begin() needed when deleting an element?

Tags: c++

Deleting the element 4th element in a vector requires the following code:

```
vector<int> v;
....
....
v.erase(v.begin()+3); // Erase v[3], i.e. the 4th element
```

I'm wondering why we need the v.begin() part.
It would be nicer just to write:

```
v.erase(3); // Erase v[3], i.e. the 4th element
```

The begin() is a member of vector so the erase method could just as well handle that part for us so that our code would be more readable and easy to understand.

There is probably a good reason and I like to know.
Can someone explain or link an explanation?
Thanks.

Comment: `std::vector<int> v = { 2, 3, 1 }; v.erase(3);` -- readable? Compare that with `std::set<int s = { 2, 3, 1 }; s.erase(3);`.

Comment: @Poriferous +3 gives 2nd element? You sir can't count.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : I fail to see your point - sorry, but why is `std::vector<int> v = { 2, 3, 1 }; v.erase(v.begin()+3);` more readable? In both case, it's trouble..

Comment: @nielsen: Does `v.erase(3)` remove the element with the value of `3`, or does it delete the element at index `3`?

Comment: @Bill Lynch - Of cause the element with index 3. How would anything else make sense? Does cout << v[3] print the element with value 3 or the element at index 3?

Comment: @nielsen: `std::set<int> s = {2,3,4,5}; s.erase(3);` will remove the element with the value `3` because it is a key value store.

Comment: @Bill - I consider a set another type than vector. However, if your point is that it is done like because all the containers shall be as identical as possible, I do see you have a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something you'd like to be able to do, it's easy enough to come up with a function template (or is it a template function?) that will do this with a slightly different, but probably similar enough syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void erase_at( T& container, size_t pos)
{
    container.erase(container.begin() + pos);
}



using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;

    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);

    for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout  << endl;

    erase_at(v, 3);  // <-- instead of `v.erase(v.begin() + 3)`

    for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `std::next(container.begin(), pos)` otherwise your `erase_at` will only work on `vector` (and potentially some custom containers).

Comment: @BillLynch: It will work on `deque` and `basic_string` as well. And restricting it to random access containers is probably a good thing.

Comment: @Michael Burr - Thanks for the code example. It inspired me to search more along that line. It brought me to B. Stroustrup book on C++ (C++11, fourth edition). Section 4.5.6 actually both contains the answer to my question and code showing how to get rid of the tedious pair-of-iterator style. Code pretty similar to your example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because of vector.erase receives iterator, but not integer.
You can see that on documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

STL developers, I think, wanted to make unique interface of erasing on all container generic classes(vector, list, etc)

Comment: That's my question: Why is it so complicated using an iterator. Why doesn't the standard just provide an erase() taking the index.

Comment: @nielsen erase by index can be efficiently implemented only on vector. Why do they need to make concrete method to vector if they already have an unique interface to all another classes?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, one of the key things here is to create a uniform interface to the standard library containers.

Let's look at `std::set<T>`, `std::vector<T>`, and `std::list<T>`. In only one of these cases do we have access to a random access iterator. In all the other cases, getting `container.begin() + 3` can be relatively expensive. Especially when the user probably has an iterator already, because they found the element exists in the object and they want to remove it.

Comment: It could be done internally like erase( std::next( begin(), 3 ) );. So it is not important whether there is a random access iterator or for example forward iterator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The point was that `std::next(begin(), 3)` is expensive for a non random access iterator.